# Detect Sprite Collision without bouncing off in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, sprite, xcode6

I am new to coding with SpriteKit / Swift and have the following problem:
A character is supposed to collect coins by jumping into them. There is no problem in detecting the collision and getting rid of the collected coin but my character bounces of the coin before it disappears.

The character is supposed to fly through the coin and collect it on the way.

```
let playerCategory: UInt32 = 0x1 << 0
let coinCategory: UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
```

---

```
player = SKSpriteNode(texture: playerTexture)
player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: player.size.height / 2)
player.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
player.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
player.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = playerCategory
player.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = coinCategory

var coin:SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: coinTexture)
coin.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: coin.size.height / 2)
coin.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
coin.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
coin.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = coinCategory
coin.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = playerCategory
```

---

```
func playerDidCollideWithCoin(player:SKSpriteNode, thisCoin:SKSpriteNode) {
    thisCoin.removeFromParent()
    coinsCollected++
}
```

Collision detection works fine like this but as I said, how can I avoid the bumping of and replace it with a "flying through"?

I'm using Xcode 6 Beta 7

Thanks in advance!

**Solution in the comment below ;)**

Comment: Set the collisionBitMask so it does not include the coin/player category. If you don't need coins to collide with anything just set it to 0. Note the difference between contact (determine overlap) and collision (receive impulse from contact).

Comment: Got it! thanks! Set the coin collisionBitMap to 0 and the player collisionBitMap to groundCategory so my player does not fall through the ground.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thee default behavior of spritekit is that everything collides with everything unless the Collision bit mask is change to 0.

Change this value in your code to 0 in all those objects that you do not want to bounce off but receive notifications from them.

```html
player = SKSpriteNode(texture: playerTexture)
player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: player.size.height / 2)
player.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
player.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
player.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = playerCategory
player.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = coinCategory
player.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0

var coin:SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: coinTexture)
coin.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: coin.size.height / 2)
coin.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
coin.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
coin.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = coinCategory
coin.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = playerCategory
coin.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
```

This will stop those objects from bouncing against each other.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. There is the third mask to set: [collisionBitMask](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsBody/collisionBitMask)

> A mask that defines which categories of physics bodies can collide with this physics body.

Given that we have:

```
enum {
    Ground = 1,
    Player = 1<<1,
    Coin   = 1<<2,
};

player.categoryBitMask = Player;
player.collisionBitMask = Ground;
player.contactTestBitMask = Ground | Coin;

ground.categoryBitMask = Ground;
ground.collisionBitMask = Player;
ground.contactTestBitMask = Player;

coin.categoryBitMask = Coin;
coin.collisionBitMask = 0;
coin.contactTestBitMask = Player;
```

The player body in this case detects contact with both ground and coin, but will only collide with the ground.